# Editing non - txt files in VB.NET

Tags: xml, json, vb.net, text-files, configuration-files

I've come across a project where I need to edit .htm, .json, .config, and .txt files with a console application in VB.NET. Now, editing the .txt file is easy, that isn't the problem. I'm wondering if, since a quick Google didn't turn anything up, there is a way to edit the other file formats, or if I just use the same methods I would for a .txt file. In short, how would I go about editing those files from VB.NET?

Comment: All of those files contain only text.  The process for reading text from them and writing text to them is the same.

Comment: Oh, good!  That's what I had hoped!  If you want to post that as an answer, I'll accept it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> .htm, .json, .config, and .txt files

Those are all text files.  The file extension doesn't really mean anything in this case, it just suggests to whatever uses the file whether or not there's a specific format to the text therein.  But it's still just text therein.

Open any of those files in Notepad, for example, and you can see that they're just text.  You'd edit them like any other text file.

Now, things like HTML, XML, JSON, and other standardized formats may have additional tools to help you manage the formatting for those.  For example with XML or JSON you might deserialize into objects, edit the objects, and serialize back into the XML/JSON format.  This would separate the reading/writing of the file from the editing of the data.  But the reading/writing parts are the same regardless of the file type.

Comment: Thanks again.  All I need to do is just replace a piece of text in each one so it shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 2):

As David said: those are all technically only text files. If you are doing simple manipulation of them, you may want to use the same methods as you use for the straight text file.

If you need to do more complex manipulation, then you may want to find specific libraries for each one.

**Json**

I have used [Json.NET](https://json.codeplex.com/) and found it to be very easy to use, very performant and quite powerful.

**XML Documents**

Included with .NET is the System.Xml namspace, which allows for working with XML documents. See [this link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317662) for additional information.

**HTML**

I haven't worked with parsing HTML before, but some quick web searches might find you what you need. My first search found the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Comment: I appreciate it, but David beat you to the punch.  All I need to do is replace a little text in each one so I shouldn't need anything fancy.